# jquery - how to change the display css attribute of a button within a li on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a `<li>` that onhover, should change the css 'display' attribute of a button within that `<li>`. The idea is that hovering over that `<li>` should make a button appear.

Right now my HTML is:

```
<li class="select-bldg-listing">
     <button class="select-bldg-btn">Review</button>
</li>
```

my CSS:

```
.select-bldg-btn {
display: none;
 }
```

jQuery:

```
$('.select-bldg-listing').hover(function () {
    $('.select-bldg-btn').css('display', 'inline-block');
},
function(){
    $('.select-bldg-btn').css('display', 'none');
});
```

But nothing happens when I mouseover on the page. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you done some debugging are you getting any javascript errors? Also careful with using classes as selectors as it will select all of the elements with that class.

Comment: Your code works http://jsfiddle.net/uDbNp/. There must be some other errors logged in the console.

Comment: Did you remember document ready ?

Comment: updated fiddle to help see what's going on. Again, it seems to be working perfectly http://jsfiddle.net/uDbNp/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this without JavaScript:

```
.select-bldg-btn {
    display: none;
}

.select-bldg-listing:hover .select-bldg-btn {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick! The jquery also worked, but this is a simpler way of achieving what I wanted to do!

Answer (score 0):

Try this -  (*should change the css 'display' attribute of a button within that `<li>`*)

```
$('.select-bldg-listing').hover(function () {
    $('.select-bldg-btn',this).css('display', 'inline-block');
},
function(){
    $('.select-bldg-btn',this).css('display', 'none');
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/F4kMH/)

Comment: If nothing is happening when using just the classes, how does adding context help ?

Answer (score 0):

This could also be done with just CSS:

```css
li.select-bldg-listing button.select-bldg-btn {
    display: none;
}

li.select-bldg-listing:hover button.select-bldg-btn {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

A comment about the naming of your classes; you include `listing` and `btn` in the classname. It is considered better practice to let your classes be "unaware" of the elements they apply to. In the CSS you specify with the `li.` or `button.` selector for which element of the class `select-bldg` you want to write a rule. This way you CSS stays cleaner and it is easier to reuse classes or rewrite them in the future.

Comment: As CSS is read right to left, using tagnames is actually in most cases less efficient.

Comment: I agree, from the browser's viewpoint. But the speed-loss is (I think) much less then the gain for the developer(s team) with respect to simplicity and maintenance. And we already gain speed by replacing JS (and jQuery) functions with simple CSS.